# Subclassing UITabBarController in storyboard when LoginView is initial view [Swift2, Xcode 7]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift2

I have an initial view that logs in or signs up a user. I am using Parse SDk, so if the user is cached, the app will automatically segue to a custom tabbarcontroller called ModelTabBarController. the reason for Subclassing the tabbarcontroller is that I want to keep references to some models that are shared between tabs. I want to do it this way as global variables in the app delegate are not encouraged by good programming standards.

My problem is that I create the ModelTabBarController class, add it as the tabbarcontroller's custom class in the storyboard identity inspector, and when I run, I get the following error in my app delegate:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

I am assuming that I am getting this issue because the ModelTabBarController is custom, and so is not initialized somehow, especially since the tabbarcontroller is not the initial view. So it cannot be added to a list of view controller items that are kept alive on the stack while the app is alive.

I am new to iOS, and it is quite complicated in my opinion. Please help me understand what is going on. I have read a lot of documentation on the iOS lifecycle, app delegates, UIWindow and such things because I presume it is an issue in the app setup.

Comment: After adding an all exception break point, here is what happens exactly, app enters loginview controller and finds cached user, segues to custom class tabbarcontroller and crashes at app delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution: I was not calling super.loadView() while attempting to override the loadView function in my custom tabarcontroller class. silly mistake.